# Period to separate items in a list?

Tags: punctuation

I was reading an article on Laptop Display, and I stumbled upon this snippet. 
Here, periods are used to separate items of a list, and I have never seen such usage. Is this actually allowed grammatically?
Following is the snippet:

Contrast. Screen Resolution. Black level. Gamut. Uniformity. These words can seem like arcane scrawl to the initiated, but they’re actually not difficult to grasp.

Comment: It works in that context.

Comment: Each of those is a sentence in its own right, so comes with a terminal period. Look at it again. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: @Lawrence Why does it?

Comment: It is *technically* ungrammatical. Those fragments can't really be considered elided sentences in any normal sense of the word. At best, the whole thing is a single fragmented sentence. However, it's stylistically acceptable.

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure, but I think it works as a set of 'headings' of sorts. The words don't work as a sentence if strung together without full-stops. They would also just 'hang in the air' if separated by commas or are otherwise treated as a list. I suppose you could use a dash or colon to connect them to *these words*, like so: "Contrast, screen resolution, ..., uniformity - these words can seem ...".

Comment: @Lawrence Dash seems to be a nice choice. I Like it.

Comment: @Lawrence No. They are not headings. Note how the first **sentence** of this comment consists of just one word. There are any number of precedents in literature, especially in literary usage.

Comment: @Kris That’s why I qualified it with “of sorts”. They are qualitatively different to imperatives and exclamations such as your “No.” And yes, I agree that they aren’t novel. The OP’s quote was artfully crafted, though.

Comment: @Lawrence Beware the pitfalls :)

Comment: yes, it's fine. punctuation is a matter of style

Answer (score 1):

If I'm going to make a list I'll put all the items one below the other and not use any punctuation at all. If it's a short list like "red, green, yellow and blue", I'll use commas. If I have to separate items like movie titles, I'll put semicolons. But I can't see anything wrong with separating items with full stops. The main thing is to keep it clear for the reader what you're listing. "Red, white and yellow." "Now, Voyager; Citizen Cane; High Noon, and many other films." (You don't confuse the reader, making them think that "Now" and "Voyager" were two different movies.) Here's what I do:

1 Don't use nuthin'. No commas, semicolons or stops in a vertical list

2 Use commas in a horizontal list

3 Use semicolons in a horizontal list

4 Use full stops (periods) in a horizontal list

5 Do what YOU think is the best to make your presentation as clear as possible

Here's a list. No punctuation marks. Isn't this clear and nice and readable?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is grammatically correct, and it is technically more proper to use commas, but as @Lawrence said in the comments, it does work in this context.

Comment: -1 See my comment at OP.

Comment: It is gramatically incorrect. See https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/vertical-lists/, which says that "Use a period after the last item in the list."

Comment: It's not a list *per se* so the reference is not relevant. Also, to use a period after the last list item is not mandatory, and most times detested by writers. Your source may not be authentic.

Comment: punctuation has naught to do with grammar

Comment: @Kris It is not a sentence because it does not have a verb.

Comment: @MichaelWang Good. And the foregoing *was* a sentence.

Answer (score -1):

These are the caption-like words written for marketing purposes, where grammar rudiments are compromised. Haven't we seen proper nouns starting in lower case, nouns being coined anew for products, etc. Tomorrow, when I write a book on the cover of which if I write, Learn the uses of "BE. BEING. BEING.", it is likely to be accepted by potential customers :)